# Getting Barcode Scanner MT2000 to Move to Next Focus

Tags: barcode-scanner, motorola, motorola-emdk, datawedge

I am trying to move to the next focus of an application by transmit a TAB or ENTER character to the host from my Motorola MT2070 Barcode Scanner.

I have tried using the SendLabel method as follows

```
       string barcode = "Hello";
       int count = 1;

        SendBarcode(new LabelData(barcode + "\t" + count.ToString(), Options.BarcodeType));
        count++;
    }

    private bool SendBarcode(LabelData label)
        {
        RESULTCODE result = RESULTCODE.E_OK;
        try
        {
            result = Program.ScannerServicesClient.SendLabel(label, 10000);
        }
        catch
        {
            result = RESULTCODE.E_HOST_NOT_READY;
        }
        if (result != RESULTCODE.E_OK)
        {
            MsgBox.Error(listForm, Properties.Resources.StrErrorCouldntSendBarcode);
        }
        return result == RESULTCODE.E_OK;
    }
```

Unfortunately the "\t" does not translate into an actual TAB keystroke in Keyboard mode.

When scanning in NOTEPAD the 5 spaces of the tab show up, but it doesn't work to move the focus to the next field as hitting TAB does in Excel or other applications.

What should I be transmitting in place of the \t?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this won't work, because it is not a normal/manual input from your keyboard. It is a value passed from a barcode to the text-property of your field. So you have to handle this different.

Comment: I figured. I am looking for solutions on how to get the barcode scanner to tell the host to tab over to the next field. 
Thanks!

Comment: If scanned barcode contains tab, focus next control.

Comment: I am unable to modify the application that barcodes are scanned into. I can only modify the application on the MT2000 barcode scanner, I am looking for information on how to have the barcode scanner transmit the equivalent TAB keystroke to focus next control to the host.